# (admin.E202) <model> has no ForeignKey to <model> With OneToOne Field Django Admin Tool

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a small app with these two models:

```
class LocationSpecialNeeds(models.Model):
    [some fields]

class Location(models.Model):
    [some fields]
    location = models.OneToOneField(LocationSpecialNeeds, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Which I want to see in the Django admin tool using this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Location, LocationSpecialNeeds

class LocationSpecialNeedsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = LocationSpecialNeeds
    can_delete = False

@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        LocationSpecialNeedsInline,
    ]
```

Which seems straightforward enough. However, I get the error:

```
<class 'locations.admin.LocationSpecialNeedsInline'>: (admin.E202) 'locations.LocationSpecialNeeds' has no ForeignKey to 'locations.Location'.
```

When I start the app. Isn't a OneToOne a foreign key relationship? What am I missing?

Comment: Foreign key is One to Many, or Many to One. So, one to one and foreign key is different